# Evaluate HOMEBREW_PREFIX inside xcode GUI

Tags: xcode, homebrew

I have a bunch of xcode libraries with lots of dependencies and search path definitions. We have several macs, some of them use Apple Silicon, some Intel.

I therefore want to use the HOMEBREW_PREFIX variable for the path definitions, since its different for the platforms.

The variable is set in my .zshrc as well as .zprofile, and is correct when evaluating in the terminal. I also tried to evaluate the variable via brew --prefix, but I could not figure how to evaluate variables this way within xcode either.

What is the correct way to use HOMEBREW_PREFIX within xcode?

Comment: why not pack your homebrew dependencies into your app's bundle? Your way of using homebrew dependency inside HOMEBREW_PREFIX makes your app unable to run if the user hasn't installed some brew components.

Comment: Its a cross platform console app and has no app bundle (xcode is used for dev and dev testing, dockerized afterwards).

Comment: Since brew is only for apple platforms, the "cross platform" here means your console app works for x84_64 macs and apple silicon macs, right?

Comment: I mean all platforms where docker runs. For CI and release builds the application is running inside an Ubuntu based image on x86, and an Alpine based image on ARM platforms. For development the application runs on either Intel or Apple silicon based macs.